# Can't create Ajax deferred dataTable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, deferred-rendering

I want to make lazy initialization dataTable that load data when clicking over page number.

I make like this to load data on request, but the table render empty table at the beginning, when click on any other number, more than 10 record appear for all page numbers, and also this caption appear " Show 41 to Nan from NaN (filtered from NaN total entries)" on clicking on page numbers, of course the number 41 change according to the clicked page number.

```
  $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
        //get total record within db
        url: url+'getTotalInst',
        success: function(total){

            var oTable = $('#institutionsTable').dataTable( {
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bAutoWidth": false,

                "sAjaxSource": "control_panel/Institution_controller/getAllInstituions",

                "aoColumns": [
                    {
                        "mData": "institution_name"
                    },
                    {
                        "mData": "institution_type"
                    },
                    {
                        "mData": "address"
                    } ,
                    { 
                        "sTitle": "Tasks",
                        "sDefaultContent":"",      // must be used to prevent "Requested unknown parameter" error                          
                        "fnRender": function(obj) {
                            var inst_id = obj.aData.inst_id;

                            var returnButton = '<span class="button-group">'+
                                '<a href=<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/updateInst/'+inst_id+' class="optionButton icon edit">edit</a>'+
                                '<a href="#" class="optionButton icon remove danger">delete</a>'+
                                '</span>';
                            return returnButton;
                        }
                    }],
                "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {

                    $(nRow).attr("id",aData.inst_id);
                    return nRow;
                },

                //for defer rendering! but not work well
                "bDeferRender": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "iDeferLoading": total,
                "iDisplayLength" : 10

            } );

        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

The Json return is huge but here is sample of it

```
 {"aaData":[{inst_id:79, institution_type:مراكز صحية, institution_name:مستشفى الشهيد كمال   عدوان,…},…],"iTotalRecords":71,"iTotalDisplayRecords":10}
```

Comment: The "NaN" values indicate you are not returning the required data from your backend URL, you should return a data array containing `ìTotalRecords, iTotalDisplayRecords` and `aaData`. I would also recommend to wrap your $.ajax() in a $().ready(), otherwise `$('#institutionsTable').dataTable({})` may try to bind to a DOM element not created yet.

Comment: The Nan problem is solved when I returned these values in json return to dataTable, but other problems still occurred.

Comment: Now it's showing 57 rows from 71 total rows at one page, and these occur not in the first refresh, no after I click on any page number, then all page numbers disappear and only one page number appear

Comment: Could you post the JSON response you got from your server?

Comment: I did, please check the edited section

Comment: I'll create a fiddle for this, let's see what we'll get from that.

Comment: Have a look at the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/XNzab/6/). I used local data to test with and it works like it should. There's one bug in your code, it should read `"iDeferLoading": total.iTotalRecords` instead of `"iDeferLoading": total,` to tell the total number of rows, also move all dataTable properties to one place instead of having one part at the bottom (i.e. `"bServerSide": true,`) and another at the top.

Comment: Can u please put the js code, it doesn't appear to me.

Comment: see my comment one line above and click the "jsFiddle" to view the HTML and JS sources.

Comment: Well, I put the static value for total and the same problems, should I make any changes on the SQL statement to limit the selected rows from value to another value??

Comment: You don't have to use a static value for `iDeferLoading`, it's just that you shouldn't use the variable `total` but `total.iTotalRecords` instead (which holds the total number of found records). The JSON data looks ok so you shouldn't need to change your SQL code.